# Gitpython git push does not raise exception when failing to push

Tags: git, gitpython

This seems to be a known issue, however I'm looking for a workaround. Anyone know of a good workaround?

https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/621

````
(Pdb) test = self.repo.remotes.origin.push(refspec=self.base_branch, progress=None, force=False)
2020-07-18 12:06:55,744|WARNING|guest|Error lines received while fetching: error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:test/test.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
(Pdb)```
````

Answer (score 1):

Since [GitPython v3.1.25](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.25/tutorial.html#handling-remotes) you can call `raise_if_error()` on the object returned by `push()` to raise an exception if the push fails. In your example this would be:

```py
self.repo.remotes.origin.push(refspec=self.base_branch, progress=None, force=False).raise_if_error()
```

Comment: This does not work for me:

`self.repo.git.push(u=["origin", "HEAD"], force=True).raise_if_error()`

gives

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'raise_if_error'`

GitPython 3.1.40

Answer (score 0):

If your push has succeeded, your local reference to `origin/branch` should be on the same commit as `branch`.

You can use that as a workaround.

---

The only case where this wouldn't work is : if you triggered `git push` while your local `branch` was at the same point as your local reference to `origin/branch`, while `branch` was updated on the actual remote.

That is : if you push without having committed anything new on the branch.
To be 100% sure : you can check before the push if `branch` is at `origin/branch`, and act accordingly (do not push ?).